# An alias for an alias?

Tags: c++, alias

Is it ok to create references for reference variables (alias for an alias in itself ) ?

If yes, what is its application ?

Comment: No, this is not possible in C++.

Answer (score 4):

In C++98, it was illegal to form references to reference types. In C++11, there are new *reference collapsing* rules, which means in a nutshell that a reference to a reference is still just a reference (but there are subtleties regarding lvalue and rvalue references). Consider this code:

```
typedef int & ir;
int a;
ir & b = a;
```

In C++98, the last line is illegal, since `ir &` is not a valid type (an attempted reference to a reference). In C++11, the references collapse and `ir &` is the same as `int &`.

Bear in mind that references are immutable, and once initialized you can never change the *target* of the reference. In the above code, `b` will always be an alias of `a`, and can never be changed into an alias to something else. Thus there is no need for a double indirection, as it wouldn't allow you to do anything more than what you already can do with ordinary references.

For completeness, the reference collapsing rules are as follows. Suppose `T` is not a reference type. Then conceptually we have:

```
(T&)& == T&    (T&)&& == T&    (T&&)& == T&    (T&&)&& == T&&
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't think that this might be what the questioner was talking about. Just to check -- the reference collapsing rules mean that `ir &` is just another way of spelling `int&`, correct? So my statement "there are no reference-to-reference types" is still true in C++11?

Comment: @SteveJessop: I have no idea what the OP is after. Indeed, there are no reference-to-reference types: Since references are immutable, there would be no reason to have such double indirection, since there's nothing that would allow you to do that you couldn't already do with the original reference.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure I don't have to make a humiliating correction :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB , thank you . Your explanation helps . For the **typedef** example you've mentioned, I do encounter an error that says I cannot assign a reference/pointer to an already existing reference, True that !

But this code segment :


`int i = 1;
int &a = i;
int &b = a;`

I don't find any issues when I print its values. Why so ? I'm not very clear as such .

Comment: @CHOCY: `i`, `a` and `b` are all views of the same integer variable. You can initialize a reference from another reference as well as from an non-reference, and in both cases you just create yet another reference to the same underlying object.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a reference to a reference, and C++ has no reference-to-reference types.

If you use a reference to initialize another reference, for example:

```
int i = 1;
int &a = i;
int &b = a;
```

Then what you've actually done is bound the *referand* of `a` to `b`. `a` is a name for the same object that `i` is a name for, and consequently `int &b = a;` has exactly the same effect as `int &b = i;`. So you have two references to the same object, `i`.

I can't immediately think of a reason to have two references in the same function, but you'd commonly create multiple references if you have a function `f` that takes a reference parameter, and passes this on to another function `g` that also takes a reference parameter. Then `f` and `g` each has a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, like this:

```
a = 1
b = a
```

after this processing, the id for "a" and "b" is the same one.

Comment: Thank you for edit my answer. Maybe we will be friends.